# Can one write a function which takes a type and returns a different type

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to write a function that takes a type and returns a (related) type.  For instance, a function which take a type called "RandomVariable" and return a type called "RandomVariableCovariance".  I guess in general the question is whether typenames can be parameters or return types.  C++0x is fine.

Comment: Say what you want to solve, maybe we can find a good design idea.

Comment: You should clarify: do you want a function that *manipulates types* (i.e. takes as a parameter the *type* `RandomVariable` and returns the type `RandomVariableCovariance`) or some kind of template function that determines its return type from the type of one of its arguments?

Comment: For a random variable, its mean is of the same type as its realizations (so it is easy to write an interface within a class that has it's underlying type as a template parameter) but its covariance is a different type (that is related but in a non-trivial way).  If the random variable is an N element vector (say a ublas vector type) then that random variable's covariance will be an N x N element matrix (say a ublas matrix type).  I'd like to not have to have the class specify explicitly the type of its covariance but be able to infer it from its realization.  I can post sample code if helpful.

Comment: @Kerrek SB & Matteo Italia let me know if that does not help clarify

Comment: @bpw1612: Probably easiest to make a trait class for your random variable! Then you can say `template <typename T> RVTraits<T>::cov_type covariance(const T & x, const T &  y);`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: so this is basically the same approach the standard took with std::strings?  Have an addition type traits class to collect all of the type information in a separate template parameter?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @bpw: Yes, like strings and `char_traits`, or algorithms and `iterator_traits` for that matter... traits are a very useful concept in generic programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do it with functions, but you can do it with template specialisations.  For example

```
template <class T>
struct ConvertType;

template <>
struct ConvertType<RandomVariable>
{
    typedef RandomVariableCovariance type;
};

int main()
{
    ConvertType<RandomVariable>::type myVar;
}
```

Defines a type `ConvertType` which is specialised to convert from `RandomVariable` to `RandomVariableCovariance`.  Its possible to do all kinds of clever type selection this way depending on what you need.

Comment: I totally overlooked your answer... :P +1.

Answer (score 2):

Typenames cannot be parameters or return values of a function; types are a compile-time thing!

Comment: This is C++0x; it's possible there.

Comment: @Nicol: C++0x is beyond what I know about!  If you write an answer that describes this, then I'll delete mine...

Comment: @Nicol: Your answer is not manipulating types (or typenames) at runtime, which is what the OP's question implies...

Answer (score 0):

This was on the long list of things for C++0x. It's why they created this odd function definition format:

```
auto FuncName(Type1 param1, Type2 param2) -> ReturnType {...}
```

It, combined with decltype, allows you to do things like this:

```
auto FuncName(Type1 param1, Type2 param2) -> decltype(param1 + param2) {...}
```

This means that the return type will be whatever you get when you call operator+(Type1, Type2).

Note that C++ is a statically typed language. You cannot do type computations at runtime. It must be done at compile time, via mechanisms like this or some form of template metaprogramming.

Comment: That's still a **compile-time** code generation feature, though, so it's not really "taking a type as an argument".

Comment: You can only do type computations at compile-time. All template metaprogramming and type-based computation, is done by the compiler. C++ is a _statically_ typed language; runtime typing is not possible.

Comment: yes, of course, I just wanted to make sure the OP is aware of that. Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Pardon my horrible C, since it's been forever since I actually worked with it:

```
typedef int RandomVariable;
typedef float RandomVariableCovariance;

RandomVariableCovariance myFunc(RandomVariable x) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: I think this is missing the point; my interpretation of the OP's question is a desire to actually return a type; i.e. manipulate types at runtime!

Comment: oh. so basically making something like a "variable variable" in c? scary... very very very scary.

Comment: That's how I read the OP's question.  If not, then he's being terribly unclear!

Comment: OP said function, not method. A c++ function is no different from a C function.

Comment: @Marc "method"? Method of the answer process? Or do you mean [Method of Modern Love](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_Modern_Love)?